# Cant get my div to go where I want it to go

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/rRVbK/

In the jsfiddle above the dark div with `hello` in it needs to be on the right side, next to the menu centered in the white space.

(for some reason the size of the site is really small but the problem still remains, It needs to be in the white space centered.)

```
<div id="all">
<div id="navigation">
        <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>1</span></a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href='#'><span>1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>3</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>2</span></a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href='#'><span>1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>3</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>3</span></a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href='#'><span>1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>2</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS is on JSFiddle

Comment: so you want that hello div to be in the center of the right white space? Or does the hello div only need to be on the right side?

Comment: yes, to the right of the blue menu, I tried a bunch of methods but couldn't get it to work without breaking something else.

Comment: can you tell the whole story of what it is? Maybe we can make the code easier than how you are doing now.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with the code being too broken, I have only a few elements, but basically I just need the div centered in the white space, because it will be the content holder for user messages/updates, it needs to be in the center, I don't think anything needs to be changed, I just need to fix the dark div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/rRVbK/1/
Solves your problem but as Chanckjh said, there are definitely better ways of arranging the divs.

```
#content
{
background-color: #ccc;
    text-align:center;
    width: 40%;
    float:right;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:37px;
    line-height:37px;
    margin-top:-37px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you have accepted answer....still, just to correct you semantic.... [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rRVbK/2/)

You have this error in your css :

```
#cssmenu {
   width :250px;
}
```

At multiple places, you have given `width` to `#cssmenu`, change that and use `float` instead...its much cleaner!

Just add this :

```
clr{clear:both}
#cssmenu{float:left}
#content{float:right;}
```

to your css and remove `250px` width!

Comment: @OP : in case if you try,lemme know if it works for u!!

Comment: I ended up actually changing my div order around and implementing a new one, here is the fiddle if you want to see it. http://jsfiddle.net/77cx7/
I separated the navigation out from the `all` div and had them apart and them put them together with a new div `test`, fixed the issue completely